# Spinner: listen to close spinner event

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a fragment with spinner and a text view.
When I close the spinner I want to hide the spinner and show only the text view.
If I select a value from the spinner's drop down list it's easy using OnItemSelectedListener, but if I just open the spinner and close it (by tapping on the screen, or on back button..) nothing happen.

Comment: you are saying you hide your spinner after onitemselectedlistener and after that you want your spinner to be back or trigger its visibility by pressing th backbutton?

Comment: No, when I open the spinner and tap on back or somewhere on the screen I want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

to hide your spinner when you click the back key.. i suppose you just do this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // you can also add a boolean to check if you've selected the spinner
    if(open){
       Toast.makeText(this, "i am hiding spinner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
       //call super function..
     }
}
```

i am answering on the logic that hide is you making your spinner invisible, to the user.. let me know if it helps

Comment: `onBackPressed` doesn't get called inside a Fragment.